# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that when pressed, should push another view controller but the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not being called. I am Using another view controller, `PhotoCell`, ad the cell is that has any impact. Thanks in advance! Here is the code for the table.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //    NSInteger sections = self.objects.count;
    //    if (self.paginationEnabled && sections != 0)
    //        sections++;
    //    return sections;
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//    if (indexPath.section >= self.objects.count) {
//        // Load More Section
//        return 320.0f;
//    }
//    
    return 320.0f;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
    PhotoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[PhotoCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    [cell setThumbImage:self.thumbImage];
    cell.imageView.image = self.thumbImage;
    [cell setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    return cell;
}

//this is what i need to look at

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"Pushing row at index path");
}
```

And here is where I defined the table

```
[self.tableView registerClass: [PhotoCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell"];
self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568) style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
[self.tableView setDelegate: self];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.tableView];
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Are you sure your controller is your tableview's delegate and datasource?

Comment: have you set up any push segue in Interface Builder?

Comment: @matthewmoss are other table delegate & data source methods working properly?

Comment: Also, why are you setting setExclusiveTouch:YES? Shouldn't the tableview worry such details itself?

Comment: No need to add a tableview as a subview to a scrollView. UITableViewController is a subclass of ScrollViewController. Just put the tableView as a subview to a view.

Comment: How do you know the method is not being called as opposed to the instructions in the method not working? Have you placed a breakpoint in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to make sure it is being called or not? Along these lines, are receiving any errors?

Comment: @YunusNedimMehel No, the rest are not working correctly either

Comment: @physics90 After adding a break point, nothing happens when the cell is pressed

Comment: does the program call the didSelectRow method and stop at the breakpoint? I tend to go overboard on the use of breakpoints and NSLog messages at times just to debug. Even if the program executes code within a method, using a breakpoint will allow you to look at the different variables etc. Are some nil, not what you expect etc. I’m sure you know this but thought I would mention just in case.

Comment: Where are you creating the tableview? As someone else pointed out, you shouldn’t need to add the tableview to a scrollview. A tableview is a scrollview. Unless you are creating some fancy interface where the tableview is a subview of the scrollview, this shouldn’t be necessary.

Comment: @physics90 There is no change when the row is seleced with or without the brake point, which, if i am correct, means that it is not being called. This is my first time using a UITableView so I just want to check.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a gesture recognizer set on your tableview? If you do it might be "swallowing" the events.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go ahead and take a blind guess, assuming that you set up a push segue in interface builder.

In such case `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` won't be called when the segue is triggered. If you need to do extra setup before the segue executes, you can implement
 `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

Comment: im not using interface builder

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was in selection property it was "No Selection". When I changed it from "No selection" to any other value didSelectRowAtIndexPath method started to work. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say the exact reasons, but there are things to try:

1. You are creating a tableView, but for some reason it won't invoke delegate & datasource methods. First of all put a breakpoint between the lines you are creating the UITableView and make sure the program runs through that code.
2. Are you using IB for that ViewController? Are there any UITableView's on the xib file? Because you are creating UITableView programatically, one UITableView might be on top of the other. Using the IB is almost always easier.
3. Remove the tableView from UIScrollView. I don't know the exact architecture here, but two scrolling views on top of each other are never a good idea and always cause problems (search UITableView on UIScrollView on stack overflow and you will see). Remember, UITableView is a UIScrollView itself.
4. Remove exclusiveTouch from your cell, that might also be causing the problem
5. Try removing the autorelease statement. You are not using ARC, so release the tableView in the dealloc method. Also use [_tableView release] not [self.tableView release].

Comment: I've checked 2-4, all worked, and if the delegate and datascource are not connected correctly, I believe a warning appears saying they are not hooked up correctly. Is this correct

Comment: No, you can add a UITableView using the IB and not connect the outlet to the vc. There will be a UITable on the vc, but there wont be any cell, nor it will trigger didSelectRowAtIndexPath or numberOfRowsInSection and similar methods

Comment: Could something like this easily happen if i'm not using interface builder and coding programaticly

Comment: @matthewmoss Don't think so, maybe it is caused by autoreleasing. Edited my answer.